# What are the propagation rules for local window settings defined in .vimrc?

Tags: vim-windows, line-numbers

In my `.vimrc` I have `:set number`.

This window-local setting is applied for new windows (e.g., when running `:split some_new_file`).

However, when I open a help window with `:help`, there are no line numbers shown, with `nonumber` set.

I am curious why this is the case.

I don't see anything in `ftplugin/help.vim` that sets no line numbers.

What are the rules for window-local settings that are defined in `.vimrc`? Which new windows will these settings be applied for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out many (most?) options in a help buffer are actually hardcoded in the C source code for Vim itself.

See [`prepare_help_buffer()`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.3356/src/help.c#L679) and the comments in that function that explain which settings are getting tweaked.

So what you're witnessing is pretty much a special case and it's pretty well hidden since you don't even get to search the Vim scripts for filetype "help" to find that setting, or to use `:verbose` to see where it's coming from.

In the general case, though:

> What are the rules for window-local settings that are defined in .vimrc? Which new windows will these settings be applied for?

See [`:help option-summary`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#option-summary), which will tell you that:

> When creating a new window the option values from the currently active window are used as a default value for the window-specific options.